# how to apply the value to drop down list

Tags: jquery

I am using drop down list in one section. when i change dropdown value and click the button. it will go to another section. In that another drop down list will be there. Value of the second drop down list will change based on first drop down list

first drop down list

```
<select class="dropdown" id="home_select">
    <option>Choose your location</option>
    <option value="bangalore">Bangalore</option>
    <option value="delhi">Delhi NCR</option>
    <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="pune">Pune</option>
    <option value="kolkatta">Kolkatta</option>
</select>
<a class="butt" id="home_btn">Schedule a HOME visit</a>
```

second drop down list

```
<select class="dropdown" id="ph_select">
    <option>Choose your location</option>
    <option value="bangalore">Bangalore</option>
    <option value="delhi">Delhi NCR</option>
    <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="pune">Pune</option>
    <option value="kolkatta">Kolkatta</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$("#home_btn").on("click", function () {
    var lct = $('#select').val();
    var slt = $('#home_select').children(":selected").attr("value");
     $('#ph_select').children("option").attr("value")=slt;
    document.location.href='#'+lct;
  });
```

Comment: When i am clicking anchor tag, it will goto that section. but i want t change the second drop down list value based in changing first dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the setter version of [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) to set the value

```
$("#home_btn").on("click", function () {
    var lct = $('#home_select').val();
    $('#dr_select').val(lct)
    document.location.href = '#' + lct;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yLZLh/)

Answer (score 0):

Even with JS it's just : ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WnfmB/))

```
var btn = document.getElementById("home_btn");
var sel1 = document.getElementById("home_select");
var sel2 = document.getElementById("dr_select");

btn.onclick = function() {  
  sel2.value = sel1.value;
}
```

Comment: but he's using jQuery

Comment: Jquery is JS. Just meant to point out that the functionality trying to be achieved here is trivial even in plain JS. One need not use Jquery just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors in your code, just check out my fixed version..

This is how the javascript needs to look

```
$("#home_btn").click( function () {
    $("#dr_select").append("<option>TEST</option>");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MbKAS/

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
$("#home_btn").on("click", function () {
    var lct = $('#select').val();
    var slt = $('#home_select').children(":selected").attr("value");
    $('#dr_select').val(slt);
    document.location.hash = '#' + lct;
});
```

1) You need to set value of the `select` using `val()`.

2) You second select id is `dr_select` not `ph_select`.

3) Use `document.location.hash` instead of `document.location.href`.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8yxR/)**